# Conditional take with LINQ

Tags: c#, enumeration, yield-return

I have a couple validators that is validating an `IDeliveryObject`, which conceptually can be described as a file with several rows. That part is working fine.

```
IEnumerable<IDeliveryValidator> _validators; // Populated in ctor. Usually around 20 different validators.

private IEnumerable<IValidationResult> Validate(IDeliveryObject deliveryObject)
{
    var validationErrors = new List<IValidationResult>();
    int maxNumberOfErrors = 10;
    foreach (IDeliveryValidator deliveryValidator in _validators)
    {
        IEnumerable<IValidationResult> results = deliveryValidator.Validate(deliveryObject).Take(maxNumberOfErrors);
        validationErrors.AddRange(results);
        if (validationErrors.Count >= maxNumberOfErrors )
        {
            return validationErrors.Take(maxNumberOfErrors).ToList();
        }
    }
    return validationErrors;
}
```

The logic iterates through a couple of validators, which all validates the file for different things.

And a validator can look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IValidationResult> Validate(IDeliveryObject deliveryObject)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(deliveryObject.FilePath))
    {
        int expectedLength = 10; // Or some other value.
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var lineLength = line.Length;
            if (lineLength != expectedLength)
            {
                // yield an error for each incorrect row.
                yield return new DeliveryValidationResult("Wrong length...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `ValidationResult` looks like this:

```
public class DeliveryValidationResult : ValidationResult, IValidationResult
{

    public DeliveryValidationResult(bool isSoftError, string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage)
    {
        IsSoftError = isSoftError;
    }

    public DeliveryValidationResult(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage)
    {
    }

    public DeliveryValidationResult(string errorMessage, IEnumerable<string> memberNames) : base(errorMessage, memberNames)
    {
    }

    public DeliveryValidationResult(ValidationResult validationResult) : base(validationResult)
    {
    }

    public bool IsSoftError { get; set; }
}

public interface IValidationResult
{
    string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    bool IsSoftError { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks to `Take(maxNumberOfErrors)` and `yield` each validator will only return 10 validationresults, which used to be fine. But now I need to handle "soft validation result", which is the same kind of validation result, but it should not be included in the number of results yielded. It's a kind of warning, which is defined by setting `IsSoftError` in `IValidationResult`. A validator can yield both "soft validation result" and "regular validation result".

What I want is to take x validation results + unlimited soft validation results, so that all `IValidationResults` with `IsSoftError == true` will be included in the collection, but not in the count. I know that it sounds weird, but the concept is that there's no need to keep validating the file after x errors, but the validation can return unlimited "warnings".

***It's very important that the Enumeration isn't enumerated more than one time, because it's CPU-heavy.*** Below is the code I want to change.

```
private IEnumerable<IValidationResult> Validate(IDeliveryObject deliveryObject)
{
    var validationErrors = new List<IValidationResult>();
    int maxNumberOfErrors = 10;
    foreach (IDeliveryValidator deliveryValidator in _validators)
    {
       // Here I want results to contain MAX 10 regular validation results, but unlimited soft validation results
        IEnumerable<IValidationResult> results = deliveryValidator.Validate(deliveryObject).Take(maxNumberOfErrors);
        validationErrors.AddRange(results);
        if (validationErrors.Count(x => !x.IsSoftError) >= maxNumberOfErrors)
        {
            return validationErrors.Take(maxNumberOfErrors).ToList();
        }
    }
    return validationErrors;
}
```

***EDIT:***
When I got 10 'hard' errors I want to stop the cycle completely. The main issue here is that the cycle **doesn't stop when 10 'soft' errors occured.**

Comment: Do you want to have a maximum of 10 non-soft errors for each validator? Or overall?

Comment: If you want to get all the soft errors. then you must enumerate until the end, even if you reach 10 non-soft errors. This means that you should only filter the final result at the end. It could be the case that there is some soft error after getting 100 non-soft errors.

Comment: Actually overall. But the solution that I have now still works where I keep track of the total and add 10 more errors for each validator. It's not that important if it's 10 + 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to completely stop after 10 'hard' errors, you could try this:

```
int count = 0;
IEnumerable<IValidationResult> results = deliveryValidator.Validate(deliveryObject)
    .TakeWhile(error => error.IsSoftError || count++ < maxNumberOfErrors);
```

this would stop when the 11th hard error is encountered.

Comment: Looks promising. I haven't used TakeWhile before. Will try it and get back to you...

Comment: Turned out that this was exactly what I was looking for. A conditional Take(). :) I didn't want to post the question because it felt like a stupid/unsolvable question, but now I'm glad I did. Thank you Manuel.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Go through all the items and sort them into Soft and NotSoft
//But ultimately these are in memory constructs...so this is fast.
var foo = Validate(delivery).ToLookup(x => x.IsSoftError);
var soft = foo[true];
var hard = foo[false].Take(10);
var result = Enumerable.Concat(soft, hard);
```

Comment: I think he wants the evaluation to stop once 10 'hard' errors occured.

Comment: @ManuelSchweigert But it must continue to get the soft errors.

Comment: @ManuelSchweigert Also the OP asked for a solution in Linq, which would neccessitate this approach, given that Linq is based in Monad Functional Programming.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I want to stop completely after 10 'hard' errors. When 10 hard errors occured I do not need to continue getting the soft errors.